# Determine when difference in two values reaches a minimum

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code with compares the values `Cd` and `Cdd`:

```
# use Python 3 print function and division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

# libraries
import numpy as np

#--- INPUTS

rhog = 1.17     # density (kg/m^3)
ug = 1.85e-5    # dynamic viscosity (kg/ms)
g = 9.81        # gravity (m/s^2)

dp = 0.000207   # diameter of particle (m)
rhos = 2500     # density of particle (kg/m^3)
sp = 0.8        # sphericity of the particle, perfect sphere = 1.0 

#--- OUTPUTS

# acceptable difference between Cd and Cdd
dn = 0.02

# determine ut when abs(Cd-Cdd) is a minimum
for ut in np.arange(0, 20, 0.001):
    Re = (dp*rhog*ut)/ug
    Cd = (24/Re)*(1+(8.1716*np.exp(-4.0655*sp))*Re**(0.0964+0.5565*sp)) + (73.69*np.exp(-5.0748*sp)*Re)/(Re+5.378*np.exp(6.2122*sp))
    Cdd = (4*g*dp*(rhos-rhog))/(3*(ut**2)*rhog)
    delta = abs(Cd-Cdd)
    if delta < dn:
        break 

print('ut =', ut)
print('Re =', Re)
print('Cd =', Cd)
print('Cdd =', Cdd)
print('delta =', delta)
```

Everything works fine except when the code is run for low values of `sp` such as `sp=0.2` which causes the criteria for `delta < dn` to never occur.

Is there a better approach to compare the `Cd` and `Cdd` terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectorized approach would be to compute all the values and then look for the minimum:

```
ut = np.arange(0, 20, 0.001)
Re = (dp*rhog*ut)/ug
Cd = ((24/Re)*(1+(8.1716*np.exp(-4.0655*sp))*Re**(0.0964+0.5565*sp)) +
      73.69*np.exp(-5.0748*sp)*Re)/(Re+5.378*np.exp(6.2122*sp)))
Cdd = (4*g*dp*(rhos-rhog))/(3*(ut**2)*rhog)
delta = np.abs(Cd-Cdd)
idx = np.argmin(delta)

print('ut =', ut[idx])
print('Re =', Re[idx])
print('Cd =', Cd[idx])
print('Cdd =', Cdd[idx])
print('delta =', delta[idx])
```

Because there is no Python looping, it is likely to run faster than your current code, even though it may be doing a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: Well that definitely looks like an elegant way to approach this. Do you know of any good resources or books that talk about vectorizing computational models in Python?

Comment: This works great. Also fixes the problem I had with defining an appropriate `delta < dn`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was originally going to be a comment, but I ran out of room.

A common approach for testing convergence to a min is the [RMSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) (Root-Mean Square Deviation) test. To compute the RMS deviation (also called `Standard Error`), compute the square root of the squared difference between `Cd` and `Cdd`, i.e. `math.sqrt((Cd-Cdd)**2)` each interval. Then, divide by the square root of the number of values you're comparing (2 in this case).

Which gives you:

```
rmsd = math.sqrt( ((Cd - Cdd)**2)/2 )
```

As the difference between the two values converges to a minimum, the RMSD will change less and less. Eventually it will only change by a small amount, and you can say the difference has converged. So, track the rmsd between iterations, and apply your `delta` to it instead:

```
if math.abs(rmsdPrior - rmsdCurrent) < delta:
    break
```

Comment: Didn't think of the RMS approach. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they are actually converging for values of `sp>0.2`? Are you sure the loop is not exiting when `ut` reaches `20`? I did some tests looping through values of `ut` from 0.0001 to 20 with increments of 1, with `sp` going from `1` down to `01` and printing the value each time through the loop. It always exits at `ut==20` and `Cd` never gets close to `Cdd`...

```
spr = range(10,1,-1)
for spv in spr:
    sp = spv/10.0
# determine ut when abs(Cd-Cdd) is a minimum
    # for ut in np.arange(0, 20, 0.001):
    for ut in np.arange(0.0001, 20, 1):
        Re = (dp*rhog*ut)/ug
        Cd = (24/Re) * (1+(8.1716*np.exp(-4.0655*sp)) * Re**(0.0964+0.5565*sp)) + (73.69*np.exp(-5.0748*sp)*Re)/(Re+5.378*np.exp(6.2122*sp))

        # Cd2 = (24/Re) * (1 + 0.14*Re**0.7)  # for a sphere sp==1

        Cdd = (4*g*dp*(rhos-rhog))/(3*(ut**2)*rhog)
        delta = abs(Cd - Cdd)
        if delta < dn:
            continue 
        # print(sp,Cd,Cdd,Re,ut,delta)
        print(sp,ut,Cd,Cdd)
```